# Generating an matrix from a set of arrays

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

```js
var set1 = [14, 9, 1, 6, 16],
  set2 = [4, 15, 16, 14, 11],
  set3 = [16, 10, 2, 3, 8],
  set4 = [3, 17, 16, 6, 14],
  set5 = [19, 18, 14, 6, 20],
  set6 = [6, 15, 8, 7, 2],
  set7 = [15, 14, 2, 19, 3],
  set8 = [8, 2, 14, 10, 5],
  set9 = [11, 6, 8, 10, 18],
  set10 = [14, 10, 12, 4, 18],
  input = [set1, set2, set3, set4, set5, set6, set7, set8, set9, set10];

// Sort function
function sortFunction(a) {

  var len = a.length,
    temp, i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
      if (a[j] < a[i]) {
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  return a;
}

// Sorting each sets and finding range of each sets
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

  input[i] = sortFunction(input[i]);
  minRange.push(Math.min.apply(null, input[i]));
  maxRange.push(Math.max.apply(null, input[i]));
}

// Finding the range of input

var minimum = Math.min.apply(null, minRange);
var maximum = Math.max.apply(null, maxRange);
var range = maximum - minimum + 1;


// Matrix table function
var tableArray = [];

function table() {
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < range; j++) {
      if (input[i][j] == j) {
        tableArray[i].push(input[i][j]);
      } else {
        tableArray[i].push(0);
      }
    }
    tableArray.push(tableArray[i]);
  }
  return tableArray;
}
```

I am having problem solving this problem: the input is a set of 10 arrays where each array contains 5 different number in range of 1 - 20.

input =[ [14, 9, 1, 6, 16], [4, 15, 16, 14, 11], [16, 10, 2, 3, 8], [3, 17, 16, 6, 14], [19, 18, 14, 6, 20], [6, 15, 8, 7, 2], [15, 14, 2, 19, 3], [8, 2, 14, 10, 5], [11, 6, 8, 10, 18], [14, 10, 12, 4, 18] ]

I would like to generate a 10x20 matrix as output where each row has has 20 numbers with the following pattern:

output = [ [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 14, 15, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0], [... ], ... ]

Im using JavaScript to solve this...

Comment: I just added my code but its a mess and I cant figure out what is wrong with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new output array:

```
var out = [];
```

Loop over the input array. For each nested array create a new array in the output array padded with 20 zeros, and then just replace those elements in the output array with the value of the element in the nest input array in the right position. Since you know the size of the nested array, and it's small, its easier just to list each element rather than use an inner loop.

```
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  var el = arr[i];
  out[i] = Uint8Array(20);
  out[i][el[0] - 1] = el[0];
  out[i][el[1] - 1] = el[1];
  out[i][el[2] - 1] = el[2];
  out[i][el[3] - 1] = el[3];
  out[i][el[4] - 1] = el[4];
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qyd9hf9d/5/)

If your browser doesn't support `Uint8Array` you can use a separate function to create a padded array:

```
function padArray() {
  var out = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = 20; i < l; i++) {
    out.push(0);
  }
  return out;
}
```

And use:

```
out[i] = padArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, Your answer works perfectly except you need to change  

  out[i][arr[i][0]] = arr[i][0];
  out[i][arr[i][1]] = arr[i][1];
  out[i][arr[i][2]] = arr[i][2];
  out[i][arr[i][3]] = arr[i][3];
  out[i][arr[i][4]] = arr[i][4];

with 
  out[i][arr[i][0]-1] = arr[i][0];
  out[i][arr[i][1]-1] = arr[i][1];
  out[i][arr[i][2]-1] = arr[i][2];
  out[i][arr[i][3]-1] = arr[i][3];
  out[i][arr[i][4]-1] = arr[i][4];

Answer (score 0):

You really should have tried it yourself. It's rather easy. Start with an array of 20 zeros, then fill the slots with the values from the array:

```
function posArray(arr, max) {
    var res = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) res.push(0);

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var a = arr[i];

        if (a > 0 && a <= max) res[a - 1] = a;
    }

    return res;
}

var output = [];

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    output.push(posArray(input[i], 20));
}
```

Comment: I just added my code and I know it's easy but I cant figure it out lol

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would also work (not tested):

```
var set1 = [14, 9, 1, 6, 16],
  set2 = [4, 15, 16, 14, 11],
  set3 = [16, 10, 2, 3, 8],
  set4 = [3, 17, 16, 6, 14],
  set5 = [19, 18, 14, 6, 20],
  set6 = [6, 15, 8, 7, 2],
  set7 = [15, 14, 2, 19, 3],
  set8 = [8, 2, 14, 10, 5],
  set9 = [11, 6, 8, 10, 18],
  set10 = [14, 10, 12, 4, 18],
  input = [set1, set2, set3, set4, set5, set6, set7, set8, set9, set10];
var output = [];

for (var e=0; e<input.length; e++) {
  newRow = [];
  for (var i=0;i<20; i++) {
    if (input[e].indexOf(i) > -1) {
      newRow.push(i);
    }
    else {
      newRow.push(0);
    }
  }
  output.push(newRow);
}
alert(output);
```